# Giving default value to generic parameter in C#

Tags: c#

I have two methods like below. And I want to collect these two method in one method.

**When I did like below two method working perfectly**

```
public static async Task<GridResult<List<T>>> GetGridResult<T, TSearchFilter>(
    this IQueryable<T> query, 
    QueryFilter<TSearchFilter> queryFilter) where TSearchFilter : class
{
}

public static async Task<GridResult<List<T>>> GetGridResult<T>(
    this IQueryable<T> query, 
    QueryFilter queryFilter)
{
}
```

So, I collecty to my methods to one method by giving default `null` value to `QueryFilter<TSearchFilter> queryFilter` .

**But, when I did one method, then gave me error**

```
public static async Task<GridResult<List<T>>> GetGridResult<T, TSearchFilter>(
    this IQueryable<T> query, 
    QueryFilter<TSearchFilter> queryFilter = null) where TSearchFilter : class
{
}
```

But I can't call my method by one parameter like `query.GetGridResult(queryFilter)`. It give me error

> 'IQueryableExtensions.GetGridResult(IQueryable, QueryFilter)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

How can I fix this error?

```
public class QueryFilter<TSearchFilter> where TSearchFilter: class
    {
        public QueryFilter()
        {
            SearchFilter = (TSearchFilter)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(TSearchFilter));
        }
        public string SortBy { get; set; }
        public bool IsSortAscending { get; set; }
        public int PageFirstIndex { get; set; }
        public byte PageSize { get; set; }
        public TSearchFilter SearchFilter { get; set; }
    }

    public class QueryFilter
    {
        public string SortBy { get; set; }
        public bool IsSortAscending { get; set; }
        public int PageFirstIndex { get; set; }
        public byte PageSize { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: What's `TSearchFilter` on last example?

Comment: What are `query` and `queryFilter` in the example? would we *expect* it to be able to infer them? it isn't obvious without that context

Comment: Rethink that design choice as the compiler wont allow what it is you are trying to attempt. Also watch out for [premature optimization](http://wiki.c2.com/?PrematureOptimization)

Comment: I added my `QueryFilter` class. to my question @SeM . I'm sending that queryFilter.

Comment: I added my QueryFilter class to my question @MarcGravell . I'm sending that queryFilter. Can you now check please? query is  `query = from student in studentEntity select new {Id = student.ID....};`

Comment: Imagine I stand at a door. I say 'you can't come in unless you tell me the type of chocolate you are holding'. The first person comes up with some white chocolate. I let them in. The second person comes up with some dark chocolate. I let them in. The third person comes up **with no chocolate at all**. I can't work out what type of chocolate they are holding (are they not holding white chocolate? or not holding dark chocolate?). So I don't let them in. Now, let's think of your problem. If you don't pass parameter, what type do you expect `TSearchFilter` to be, and why?

Comment: Thanks @mjwills . I understand that my main problem is sending QueryFilter instead of QueryFilter<TSearchFilter> . So, C# can't know this.

Answer (score 2):

As `null` has no type it can't determine what the type of `TSearchFilter` is. You could call the method by specifying the types e.g. `query.GetGridResult<string, object>(queryFilter)`, so that even though you might not use the object `null` it still is valid in your context.

I would honestly just keep it 2 seperate methods and have one call the other more detailed one.

Comment: Thanks @Bleep-Bloop. I understand that my main problem is sending QueryFilter instead of QueryFilter<TSearchFilter> . So, `query.GetGridResult<string, object>(queryFilter)` won't solve my issue. I have to use two method. There is no other solution.

Answer (score 1):

Because you're trying to call a method with generic parameter `QueryFilter<TSearchFilter> queryFilter` with the value of non-generic class `QueryFilter`, which is not anyhow related to the generic one.

Edit: If you wish to use a single method, then `QueryFilter` must be derived from `QueryFilter<TSearchFilter>`.

Comment: Thanks a lot @MariePichova. You're right. I understood reason of error from your answer. My method want  `QueryFilter<TSearchFilter>` . And I'm sending `QueryFilter`. So, it give me error . Reason of the error is this. But, I think it's impossible solve this issue. Because, I can't derive QueryFilter from `QueryFilter<TSearchFilter>` . Because it's generic.

Answer (score 1):

**I found the answer by help of @MariePichova's answer.** I changed my QueryFilter class like below. And then everything worked.

```
public class QueryFilter<TSearchFilter> where TSearchFilter : class
{
    public QueryFilter()
    {
        SearchFilter = (TSearchFilter)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(TSearchFilter));
    }
    public string SortBy { get; set; }
    public bool IsSortAscending { get; set; }
    public int PageFirstIndex { get; set; }
    public byte PageSize { get; set; }
    public TSearchFilter SearchFilter { get; set; }
}

public class QueryFilter : QueryFilter<EmptySearchFilter>
{ }

public class EmptySearchFilter
{ }
```